# How to approach the integration of $ \int _0^3\:\frac{1}{\left(9-x^2\right)^{{1}/{2}}}\:dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

I'm a bit confused on what to do with the 1/2 power and how to transform the upper limit 3 after converting into a trig. I initially thought that the x in the denominator will turn into $\cos(t)^3$. But I think I am wrong here. Any tips would be greatly appreciated!

$$\int_0^3\dfrac{1}{\left(9-x^2\right)^{{1}/{2}}}\:dx$$

Comment: Hint: Try the substitution $x=3\sin(t)$

Answer (score 7):

My thought process would be:

"It would be nice if the function inside the squareroot was square so I end up with just a function"

i.e.
$$\sqrt{f^2(t)}=f(t)$$
so we need to determine a function $f(t)=x$ s.t. $9-x^2$ is a "nice function". Notice that:
$$9(\cos^2t+\sin^2t)=9$$
so:
$$9-(3\sin t)^2=(3\cos t)^2$$
let $x=3\sin t\Rightarrow dx=3\cos t\,dt$ and so:
$$\int_0^3\frac{1}{\sqrt{9-x^2}}dx=\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{9\cos^2t}}3\cos t\,dt=\int_0^{\pi/2}dt=\frac{\pi}{2}$$

Comment: That's correct but note that the integrand blows up at $x=3$ so you have an improper integral. If you are extra-cautious, you should inegrate from 0 to $b$ and take the limit as  as $b \to 3^-$.

Comment: @P.Lawrence yes you are correct- although with integrals it is implied as an open interval right?

Comment: @P.Lawrence Thank you immensely! For future reference, are you taking the inverse of 3 in the limit because you are using d/dx for the integral?

Comment: @HenryLee Thank you!! I do believe this is an open interval because of -3,3 there isn't a definite point

Comment: @P.Lawrence yes so the limits are $\arcsin(0/3)$ and $\arcsin(3/3)$